# WebView refresh every time

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

I have a flutterflow app in that I have 2 pages both have WebView I every time I swicth page page refresh I don't want that if I visit page once it should be as I left it can I do that and if I can how ? it will be very helpful for me if anybody reply's even if you don't know but use flutterflow reply it will let me know you and we can work together in future .

I tried html elements too like iframe but it also refresh

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First understand the scenario. Let's say you came to the screen that contains webview so it starts init state and load the provided URL. But problem is that whenever you come it will restarts the whole screen and it rebuilds.

One possible thing that I thought is we can maintain the state where we can track like weather the page is already visited or not that helps to not load second time. But question is how many times it should not allow to load because it is possible like data updates.

There is also one solution but it needs custom coding widget which I use to code every time when I work on any flutter flow project. See this example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WebViewPageState createState() => _WebViewPageState();
}

class _WebViewPageState extends State<WebViewPage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  late WebViewController _controller;
  final _key = UniqueKey();

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // You can load WebView logic here.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return PageStorage(
      key: _key,
      child: WebView(
        // WebView configurations will come here.
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here we can use **AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin** and **PageStorageKey** to maintain the state of widgets across page transitions.